# React issue with lodash and setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

I have an issue with using Lodash + setInterval.

What I want to do:
Retrieve randomly one element of my object every 3 seconds

this is my object:

```
    const [table, setTable]= useState ([]);
```

so I start with that:

```
const result = _.sample(table);
   console.log(result);
```

console give => Object { label: "Figue", labelEn: "fig" }

But if a add :

```
const result = _.sample(table);
   console.log(result.label);
```

console give => TypeError: result is undefined

Beside that I tried to add setInterval and also try with useEffect but or code crash or console give me two numbers every 3 second => 2,6,2,6 ......

Comment: Usually `TypeError: result is undefined` appears when `table` is empty. Are you sure that when you call `_.sample(table);`, `table` is not empty?

Comment: yes sir  i'm sure !

Comment: @Jildo I think Giovanni is correct.  What we haven't seen is what your setInterval code looks like.  When is setInterval called? Is this interval created in a useEffect hook or is it done inline before the JSX is returned? If you create an interval outside of an effect, then a new interval should be created after every render which will certainly give you unexpected results

Comment: Where is `console.log(result.label)` placed? If it's not placed in a callback, but in main context of the function component then the error makes a lot of sense. Your default `table` value is `[]`, which would means `result = _.sample([])` aka `undefined` on the initial render.

Comment: Thanks for your help 3limin4t0r !

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, supposing that `table` object is correclty filled, you could use `lodash` and `setInterval` to get random object of `table` using `useEffect` and `useRef` hooks like:

```
const interval = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!interval.current) {
      interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        const result = _.sample(table);
        console.log(result.label);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [table]);
```

Then to clean `setInterval` when component will be unmount you could use another `useEffect` in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      interval.current = null;
    };
  }, []);
```

**EDIT**

After your explanation, I found the cause of your problem. Before start `setInterval` you have to wait that `table` was filled with values (otherwise you get an error).

To solve that it's just necessary to put another condition on first `useEffect` (`table.length > 0`), and load data on second `useEffect`.

So the first `useEffect` becomes:

```
  const interval = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!interval.current && table.length > 0) {
      interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        const result = _.sample(table);
        console.log(result.label);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [table]);
```

And the second one:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    jsonbin.get("/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474/5")
     .then(({data}) => setTable(data));

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
      interval.current = null;
    };
  }, []);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-8wn9y?file=/src/index.js) the codesandbox updated.

Comment: Do you have an idea of what i suppose to do ?

Comment: @Jildo Oh ok now I understand from @3limin4t0r answer the cause of your problem. As he said, is because you are accessing to `table` before data is loaded. So you have at first wait until `table` has values, then start the `setInterval`. I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh yes I understand now, it make sense, i'm waiting for your update to see how you manage that. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Ok works perctely ! Just to understand better why table was empty ? It's because data make more time to be loaded than the useEffect with interval to be execute ?

Comment: Exactly, component will be mounted and both `useEffect` will fired immediately. So we put the condition `table.length > 0` to wait that data comes. When data comes, we launch `setTable`, `table` will be filled and only at this time we can start `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you access `table` before it is loaded.

You should either provide an initial value to that allows a successful do all your operations:

```
// use an array that has at least one element and a label as initial table value
const [table, setTable] = useState([{label: "default label"}]);

useEffect(() => {
  jsonbin.get("/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474/5")
         .then(({data}) => setTable(data));
});

const result = _.sample(table);
console.log(result.label);

// ...
```

Or use an `if` or something alike to handle multiple scenarios:

```
// use an empty array as initial table value
const [table, setTable] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  jsonbin.get("/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474/5")
         .then(({data}) => setTable(data));
});

const result = _.sample(table);
// account for the initial empty table value by checking the result
// of _.sample which is `undefined` for empty arrays
if (result) {
  console.log(result.label);
} else {
  console.log("do something else");
}

// ...
```

If you fetch your data asynchronously you must think about what you want to use while the data is being fetched. The minimal thing to do is tell React to not render the component while the data is missing (being fetch).

```
const [table, setTable] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  jsonbin.get("/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474/5")
         .then(({data}) => setTable(data));
});

const result = _.sample(table);
if (!result) return null; // <- don't render if there is no result

console.log(result.label);

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot now I understand why it didn't works and how to manage this kind of code.